# Any succesful document management sytem (application using documents intensively) using sql server filestream?

Tags: sql-server, filestream, documents

Did anyone create a Document Management System using SQL SERVER's Filestream?

By this I mean: if an application makes intensive use of documents is filestream a good option, or in those cases it would be better to go for another solution?

I understand this depends on many factors, but in general my guess is that if "<5%" than server load is based on reading/writing varbinary(max) filestream fields for sure it is good, if ">95%" than server load is based on reading/writing varbinary(max) filestream fields probably it is not ok.

So somehow I'd like to know if any of you developed applications where that % is somehow in the middle of 5 and 95 and it confirms that filestream was a good choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the apps I have recently produced is a multiple choice testing system with training materials hosted on the SQL server in the filestream. As the actual taking of the tests uses up very little “bandwidth” I would say that about 30% of the servers time is taken up by serving up these files.

So far so good, the system is about to go live to a much larger user base so only time will tell but I’m confident that it will meet the performance criteria. Filestream really is a good compromise between the camps of storing BLOBS and storing a link to a file

Comment: Ok thanks, this is reassuring for me. I will start prototyping now, anyway these are those kind of "stop or continue" informations needed.

Comment: @UnDiUdin Did you actually finish your Document Management System using SQL SERVER's Filestream? Was it any good?